# Send Html Tables to Multiple Excel Sheets

Tags: c#, html, excel

I have two html tables that I'd like to put in 2 different sheets of the same excel file. I'm using ASP.net MVC3 and sending a FileResult to my page.

The FileResult contains the following (minus the string builder):

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
        sb.Append("<head>");
        sb.Append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=windows-1252\">");
        sb.Append("<!--[if gte mso 9]>");
        sb.Append("<xml>");
        sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        sb.Append(String.Format("<x:Name>{0}</x:Name>", ExcelSheetName));
        sb.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sb.Append("<x:Panes></x:Panes>");
        sb.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");

        // sheet 2
        sb.Append("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
        //sb.Append("<x:Table/>");
        //sb.Append("<x:Column x:Width=\"500\" />");
        //sb.Append("<x:Column x:Width=\"500\" />");
        //sb.Append("</x:Table/>");
        sb.Append(String.Format("<x:Name>Sheet2_Test</x:Name>"));
        //sb.Append("<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount=\"2\" ss:ExpandedRowCount=\"5\" x:FullColumns=\"1\" x:FullRows=\"1\">");
        //sb.Append("<Row><Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Text in cell A1</Data></Cell></Row>");
        //sb.Append("<Row><Cell ss:StyleID=\"s21\"><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Bold text in A2</Data></Cell></Row>");
        //sb.Append("<Row ss:Index=\"4\"><Cell ss:Index=\"2\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">43</Data></Cell></Row>");
        //sb.Append("<Row><Cell ss:Index=\"2\" ss:Formula=\"=R[-1]C/2\"><Data ss:Type=\"Number\">21.5</Data></Cell></Row>");
        //sb.Append("</Table>");
        sb.Append("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sb.Append("<x:Panes></x:Panes>");
        sb.Append("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
        sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");

        sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
        sb.Append("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
        sb.Append("</xml>");
        sb.Append("<![endif]-->");
```

Then I add my html tables and return the result. It's working great and I got the 2nd sheet to show up, but I can't figure out how to write to that 2nd sheet. Does anyone know how to write to a 2nd sheet using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Each sheet should have its own `<Worksheet>` element. Each `<Worksheet>` node then has its own `<Table>` element, which has one or more `<Row>` elements, which has one or more `<Cell>` elements.